# Http get with JSON parameter calls Non parameter server side get function

Tags: angular

Im facing an issue with Angular get method. Here is my get method declaration.

```
var params = { "id": templateCategoryId };
        this.http.get(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/UserList', { params: params }).subscribe(result => {.....
    ......
```

And here is the server side function

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a single user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    [ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            Models.Users.AppUserDetail appUserDetail = await AppUserService.LoadAsync(id);
            if (appUserDetail == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(appUserDetail);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, "Get([{0}])", id);
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Also there is another server side function without parameter is as follows...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the list of all non-deleted application users.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(await AppUserService.LoadUserListAsync());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, "Get()");
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

But whenever the http get method invokes from Angular the second function without parameter being called even there is JSON parameter mentioned.
I didnt understand what I did wrong. Very new to Angular.

Comment: You are passing the `id` as a query parameter, but in your action it is part of the route. Try `this.http.get(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/UserList/' + templateCategoryId).subscribe(...)`

Comment: Waw.. thats perfect.. I tried and it seems to be working... But just a clarification if you dont mind.. If I need that way of parameters to server, how can I modify the server side function to accept it... Means if its query parameter how can I handle it in server..
Also if its without modifying the server side function if I need multiple parameters to send, in what way the url should be..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your `id` as a query parameter, but the action gets it from the route.

Change your angular request to

`this.http.get(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/UserList/' + templateCategoryId).subscribe(...)`

This is the right way to pass query parameters, the problem here is that you have defined `id` in the route with `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]`

If you change it to `[HttpGet("")]` and use your angular code it should work

Comment: If I use [HttpGet("")] and this way of get request  this.http.get(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/UserList', { params: params })

How can I read those parameter values in server side?
Do I need to specify all parameters in method defenition itself like this
[HttpGet("")]
        [ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
        {
}

Comment: Yes, you cannot access them without specifying them in the action method body.